# Определение pегиона по IP

Tags: c#, геолокация

Каким образом можно определить регион по IP в консольной программе?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Возьмите любой [бесплатный сервис геолокации](https://freegeoip.net/), сделайте к нему запрос и выведите результат:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication27
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for location response...");

            var locationResponse = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://freegeoip.net/xml/");
            Console.WriteLine("Raw location response:");
            Console.WriteLine(locationResponse);

            var responseXml = XDocument.Parse(locationResponse)
                .Element("Response");

            Console.WriteLine("You are in {0}, {1}.", 
                responseXml.Element("City").Value,
                responseXml.Element("CountryName").Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь